# 2 inputs side by side and their error messages under it aligned

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I have created a pen for my problem:

http://codepen.io/helloworld/pen/QpRxNr?editors=1100

I am showing 2 inputs with each an error message in a tables column.

The design is too long for my taste to be within in ONE table column.

I want that the 2 inputs are side by side and each error message is directly aligned to the left and under its input counterpart.

Just like in that mockup I did when both fields have no values entered:

[image]

How can I do that?

The solution should consider that both input must take the whole width of the table column. I do not want a bootstrap container->row->2-columns solution for that, as there should be no margin/padding to the left right of the table column.

I prefer a flexbox solution which can also use the bootstrap flex utilities :-)

```
<table> 
<td [formGroup]="customerForm" style="display:flex">

        <input  class="form-control" placeholder="First name" type="text" formControlName="firstName" />
        <div *ngIf="customerForm.controls.firstName.touched">
            <div class="form-error" *ngIf="customerForm.controls.firstName.hasError('required')">
                first name is required.
            </div>
        </div>

        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Last name" type="text" formControlName="lastName" />
        <div *ngIf="customerForm.controls.lastName.touched">
            <div class="form-error" *ngIf="customerForm.controls.lastName.hasError('required')">
                last name is required.
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done solely with the Bootstrap 4 flexbox utils, so you don't need the custom CSS.

**Option 1:** Put the 2 inputs/errors in their own divs, set `d-flex` on the `td`...

```
        <td class="d-flex">
            <div class="mr-3">
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="First name" type="text" formcontrolname="firstName">
                <div *ngif="customerForm.controls.firstName.touched">
                    <div class="form-error" *ngif="customerForm.controls.firstName.hasError('required')">
                        first name is required.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Last name" type="text" formcontrolname="lastName">
                <div *ngif="customerForm.controls.lastName.touched">
                    <div class="form-error" *ngif="customerForm.controls.lastName.hasError('required')">
                        last name is required.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
```

**Option 2:** Leave HTML structure as is, and use utils for width and flexbox order...

```
        <td class="d-flex flex-wrap">
            <input class="form-control w-50 flex-first" placeholder="First name" type="text" formcontrolname="firstName">
            <div *ngif="customerForm.controls.firstName.touched" class="w-50">
                <div class="form-error" *ngif="customerForm.controls.firstName.hasError('required')">
                    first name is required.
                </div>
            </div>
            <input class="form-control w-50 flex-first" placeholder="Last name" type="text" formcontrolname="lastName">
            <div *ngif="customerForm.controls.lastName.touched"  class="w-50 flex-last">
                <div class="form-error" *ngif="customerForm.controls.lastName.hasError('required')">
                    last name is required.
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
```

[Here is the demo](http://www.codeply.com/go/HEgWto9nta)

Comment: Then you came along... I like your solution most as it is BS4 based what I said is fine. What I did not like about your solution the gap was missing between the inputs, but your flexbox code gave me ideas: I put an extra div with padding: 5px around each input + errordiv and an extra justify-content-around to the parent td-tag. Each input has w-80. That way I have a 'margin' between the left and right input+error messages :-) Thanks!